# Char array error, expected an expression, error

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code,  I want to initialize the char array to NULL.

getting the following error

**error: 
expected an expression
g_device->name1[NAME_LENGTH-1] = {'\0'};**

```
typedef struct device_ {

    uint32_t id;
    char name1[NAME_LENGTH];
    char name2[NAME_LENGTH];

} device_t;

device_t  *g_device = NULL;


void init_device(void)
{

    g_device = malloc(sizeof(device_t));
    g_device->id = 0;
    g_device->name1[NAME_LENGTH-1] = {'\0'};
    g_device->name2[NAME_LENGTH-1] = {'\0'};
}
```

Comment: `{'\0'}` is not a valid expression in C. You probably want `g_device->name1[0] = '\0';` (note, place `'\0'` in the beginning).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assign arrays in C, plus the types don't match anyway, `g_device->name1[NAME_LENGTH-1]` is a `char` and  `{'\0'}` is a `char[1]`.

Use strcpy:

```
strcpy( g_device->name1 , "" );
```

or manually terminate the array:

```
g_device->name1[0] = '\0';
```

Notice that you should set the first character to 0, not the last.

The above two examples will of course leave other elements uninitialized, so if you wanted to initialized them to 0, use memset or a loop:

```
memset( g_device->name , '\0' , NAME_LENGTH * sizeof( char ) );
```

or:

```
for( size_t index = 0 ; index < NAME_LENGTH * sizeof( *g_device->name ) ; index++ )
{
    g_device->name[index] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use calloc to allocate the buffer, i.e.

```
g_device = calloc(1, sizeof(device_t));
```

This will allocate a buffer, which is completly filled with Zeroes, i.e. there's no need for further initialization of the character array.

Comment: Zeroes, not `NULL`. And the zeroes are interpreted like `nul` (`\0`). (nitpick)

Comment: You're right, my answer was imprecise at this point. I adapted the answer